# Align three images horizontally

Tags: graphics, align

I have three images that don't have the same size. I want to arrange them horizontally in a way that they are centered. I tried this code, it works for the positionning. But I don't know how I can add a subcaption to each image and a caption for the whole figure package like in the figure below.

```
   \begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{image_a}}}$
  \qquad
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{image_b}}}$
  \qquad
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{image_c}}}$
\caption{image}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\vcenter` method you found is not for images in a `figure` environment. Look at the `subcaption` package.

Comment: then how I can align horizontally three images with different size. I tried with minipage but it doesn't work, it doesn't center horizontally all the images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `subfigure` environment from the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{this is the first subfigure}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=7cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{this is the second subfigure}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=7cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{this is the third subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I just came across your answer while searching on a similar topic. I want to do the same with "beamer." But when I'm doing as you've suggested, I get "Environment subfigure undefined."

Comment: How can I do the same but aligning the captions at the bottom while the images are center-aligned as in the figure of this answer?